# Why can't I load data from Amazon S3 in DSX notebook?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, data-science-experience

I used the following code to load the data from Amazon S3:

```
from ingest import Connectors
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

S3loadoptions = { 
                  Connectors.AmazonS3.ACCESS_KEY          : 'AKIAJYCJAFZYENNPACNA',
              Connectors.AmazonS3.SECRET_KEY          : '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',
              Connectors.AmazonS3.SOURCE_BUCKET       : 'ngpconnector',
              Connectors.AmazonS3.SOURCE_FILE_NAME    : 'addresses3.csv',
              Connectors.AmazonS3.SOURCE_INFER_SCHEMA : '1',
              Connectors.AmazonS3.SOURCE_FILE_FORMAT  : 'csv'}

S3DF = sqlContext.read.format('com.ibm.spark.discover').options(**S3loadoptions).load()
S3DF.printSchema()
S3DF.show(5)
```

But when I run this code snippet, I get the following error. I get a similar error message when I load from another data source, such as dashDB.

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9da344857d7e> in <module>()
      4 
      5 S3loadoptions = { 
----> 6                   Connectors.AmazonS3.ACCESS_KEY          : 'AKIAJYCJAFZYENNPACNA',
      7                   Connectors.AmazonS3.SECRET_KEY          : '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',
      8                   Connectors.AmazonS3.SOURCE_BUCKET       : 'ngpconnector',

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'AmazonS3'
```

Comment: The error states that there is no "Connectors" in "ingest". Are you sure you're importing from the correct library?

Comment: Please do not create a new SQLContext. Notebooks on DSX already have one.

Comment: Check the Spark version you have selected. iirc, there are different versions of the ingest library for Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.x. Also, Python 2.7 vs. Python 3.5 could play a role.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this alternative to ingest if you would like.

https://datascience.ibm.com/blog/use-ibm-data-science-experience-to-read-and-write-data-stored-on-amazon-s3/

For spark 1.6

```
hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
```

For spark 2.0

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
hconf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
```

Set the S3 parameters in hadoop configuration

```
#Replace Accesskey with your Amazon AccessKey and Secret with amazon secret 
hconf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "<put-your-access-key>")  
hconf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "<put-your-secret-key>")
```

Then to read

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()  
df_data_1 = spark.read\  
 .format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat')\
  .option('header', 'true')\
  .load('s3a://<your-bucket-name>/<foldername>/<filename>.csv')
df_data_1.take(5)
```

To write Back

```
df_data_1.write.save("s3a://charlesbuckets31/FolderB/users.parquet")
```

Thanks,
Charles.